# Scrape post generate dom elements from stock flare

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

Wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction on how I would be able to scrape the data from this website. I understand the data is filled in after the page is fully loaded, and have seen js libraries that can request the data be loaded, but can't remember the name of them. I prefer to code in python though if possible.

https://stockflare.com/stocks/BBY

I think this would work. Found it from another answer regarding react webpages. Can anyone confirm?

[python-casperjs](https://github.com/casperjs/python-casperjs)

Comment: There are many similar questions that might help you, search for "scrape generated": https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scrape+generated+is%3Aq

Answer (score 0):

It's not legal to scrape our data. :( Please drop me a message if you'd like to work with us. Shane at Stockflare dot com.

Shane

Comment: Ok, I might at a later date. Thanks.